# Can't click a link because of z-index

Tags: html, css

I have the following: http://jsfiddle.net/5mbK8/2/

The text `Link` is supposed to function as a link, but it doesn't work because `.container .image` has a z-index of -1. If I remove the z-index, it works, but then the image isn't behind the yellow shadow.

How can I make the text clickable while keeping the background image behind the yellow box shadow?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="side"></div>
    <div class="image" style="background: url('http://i.imgur.com/T0VWLqZ.png');">
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.container {
    width: 900px;
    height: 300px;
}

.container .image {
    width: 598px;
    height: 300px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}

.container .side {
    float: left;
    width: 302px;
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
    box-shadow: 5px 0 5px -5px yellow;
}

.container .image .menu {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -25px;
}

.container .image .menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}

.container .image .menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    background: white;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5mbK8/5/

A solution would be to position the menu outside the `.image` div.
And of course you will have to adapt the `left: 300px;` depending on what width the `.side` will have.

**EDIT** (added code):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="side"></div>
    <div class="image" style="background: url('http://i.imgur.com/T0VWLqZ.png');">      </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 900px;
    height: 300px;
}

.container .image {
    width: 598px;
    height: 300px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}

.container .side {
    float: left;
    width: 302px;
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
    box-shadow: 5px 0 5px -5px yellow;
}

.container .menu {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 300px;
}

.container .menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}

.container .menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    background: white;
}
```